# Scatter visualization of a time series data in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, scatter-plot

I am working on vehicles arrival time data with the size of around 28000. The time is saved based on the date and time.

Besides `matplotlib.pyplot.histogram`, how can I visualize the distribution of the arrival time (hour/minute/second) of vehicles? (imagine that a lot of vehicles arrive at 14:00 so peak in the histogram)

I am looking at bubble plot, but that is confusing because my data has only one dimension (the time each vehicle arrived)

The dataset looks like this:

```
(0, Timestamp('2018-04-25 11:08:04+0000', tz='UTC')) (1, Timestamp('2018-04-25 13:45:10+0000', tz='UTC')) (2, Timestamp('2018-04-25 13:45:50+0000', tz='UTC')) (3, Timestamp('2018-04-25 14:37:06+0000', tz='UTC')) (4, Timestamp('2018-04-25 14:40:34+0000', tz...
```

If anyone can help me out that would be appreciated!

Comment: Your "dataset" is not in the form of a data structure.  Do you have your data in a list or a set?

Comment: The data is basically taken from a pandas data frame and the type of data is Timestamp. The data can be easily invoked by "dataset.dt.hour" or "dataset.dt.minute" or "dataset.dt.second".